# Shiny r- How to disable checkboxgroup input after it is clicked?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to disable a checkboxgroup element once it is clicked in shiny r?

I tried to figure out the problem, but without success. I add the checkboxgroup on which i am working.
Thanks for your help!

```html
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("a","A",choices = 1:7),
  tags$head(HTML(
    '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("a").disabled=true;
    }
    </script>
    '
  ))
  ))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  

  })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `shinyjs` package which conveniently comes with a `disable` function.  You can trigger the disable with an `observeEvent` where the event is the checkbox value.  The only caveat of using `shinyjs` is to incldue the function `useShinyjs` in your app's ui.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  checkboxGroupInput("a","A",choices = 1:7)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$a, shinyjs::disable("a"))
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The package has additional functions such as `enable` to enable a disabled element or `toggleState` to switch the element between the states of enabled/disabled.

---

### Disabling Single Checkbox from a checkboxGroupInput

The `disable` function of `shinyjs` has a selector argument that can used to identify which elements to disable without using their shiny id.  The way I identified what the correct query to pass to the selector was by using the [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/).  The gadget gave a did not include the shinyid so I added a "B" checkbox group, and sure enough the id changed to include the shiny id "a" so I'm fairly confident this should work after adding more elements to the shiny App.  Once the selector query was known the rest of the solution was identifying the label of which checkbox in the group was clicked, and building the string for the `disable` function to use.  Hope this helps.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  #original checkbox group
  checkboxGroupInput("a","A",choices = 1:7),
  #additional checkbox group to identify how to work around multiple groups
  checkboxGroupInput("b","B",choices = 1:7)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  #initialize reactive values (will use to store selected boxes to identify newest selection)
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  #initialize selected boxes to NULL
  rv$selectedBoxes <- NULL 
  
  observeEvent(input$a, {
    #extract newest selection by identifying which values are in a that have not been previously selected
    newSelection <- input$a[which(!(input$a %in% rv$selectedBoxes))]
    #create object that identifies newly selected checkbox (syntax found using selectorgadget)
    subElement <- paste0("#a .checkbox:nth-child(", newSelection,") label")
    #disable single checkbox of group
    shinyjs::disable(selector=subElement)
    #store all selected checkboxes
    rv$selectedBoxes <- input$a
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a very helpful advice. Do you think that could be possible to disable just the element clicked, instead of all the checkboxgroup?

Comment: Since the whole checkboxgroup is a single element with a single ID, I am not certain if shinyjs can easily handle the issue of disabling a single box within the group.  I can do some research on the issue and report back if there is a simple solution.

Comment: @L.Rop I added some to my answer that appears to accomplish what you're after

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your precious help!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

```
tags$head(HTML(
    '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("a").disabled=true;
    }
    </script>
    '
  ))
```

Should be:

```
tags$script(HTML(
    '
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("a").disabled=true;
    }
    '
  ))
```

This still doesn't work because `checkboxGroupInput` doesn't have an onclick event. If you use a different HTML element for `"a"` it works:

```html
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  actionButton("a","A"),
  tags$head(HTML(
    '
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("a").disabled=true;
    }
    '
  ))
  ))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  

  })
```

Comment: Instead of `onclick`, you can probably run the JS code on the document ready event.