# How to use checkbox:nth-child with inline checkboxGroupInput?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, jquery-selectors, shinyjs

In following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276632/shiny-r-how-to-disable-checkboxgroup-input-after-it-is-clicked) if the `checkboxGroupInput` has `inline=TRUE` then `disable(selector="#a .checkbox:nth-child(1) label")` will no longer disable the option.  Is there a tweak to the selector string?  I tried changing it to `checkbox-inline` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `inline=TRUE` parameter, the `label` elements are not under a `div`, therefore you can make the reference directly to the labels.

```R
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  checkboxGroupInput("a", "A", choices = 1:7, inline = TRUE)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$a, shinyjs::disable(selector="#a label:nth-child(1)"))
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just have to adjust the JS query collector. Try to adjust this accordingly

```
subElement <- paste0("#a .checkbox-inline:nth-child(", newSelection,") input")
```